# Classification using superClass in R

Tags: r, classification, spatial, raster

I want to make supervised classification of several land covers (4 classes). 
I intend to use R for this, with the function 'superClass' from the 'RStoolbox', using the RandomForest method.

The syntax of the function looks like:

```
superClass(img, trainData, valData = NULL, responseCol = NULL,
  nSamples = 1000, polygonBasedCV = FALSE, trainPartition = NULL,
  model = "rf", tuneLength = 3, kfold = 5, minDist = 2,
  mode = "classification", predict = TRUE, predType = "raw",
  filename = NULL, verbose, overwrite = TRUE, ...)
```

The way I scripted it, I do not use all the possible strings:

```
class1 <- superClass(img = IR_extr, model = "rf", trainData = train, responseCol = "Macroform")
```

However, using this script, R yields the error: 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  object 'RASTER[dataSet[, "cells"]]' not found

Looking into the raster imagery, this should contain values from 1-255. However, the data appears not to be linked to cells? Originally I exported this layer from ArcGis as a GeoTiff file and imported this in R. 
How can I make sure what the problem in this raster file is? 
I can make the raster file available if necessary.

Comment: This problem is solved by formatting the Raster files into RasterBrick files with the brick function.